# when I try debug, was good. but logcat catched

Tags: android, reference, android-manifest, logcat

[image]

why appear like this ??
I already have dot front of android:name
plz help me another question will be solve after this

```
09-05 21:40:33.503 17249-17249/android.nfctest D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
```

09-05 21:40:33.504 17249-17249/android.nfctest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: android.nfctest, PID: 17249
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

```
ComponentInfo{android.nfctest/android.nfctest.SecondActivity}: 

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:724)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:792)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:525)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:446)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2544)
at android.nfctest.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:15)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 780337164 byte allocation with 16766304 free bytes and 229MB until OOM
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:700)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:535)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1179)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:770)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:621)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1727)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:945)
    09-05 21:40:33.504 17249-17249/android.nfctest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:157)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:145)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:141)
... 29 more
```

Comment: add your logcat as text not as a image

Comment: By looking at the image it looks like you're missing `>` Enclosing XML activity tag

Comment: sorry, I'm super beginner ...

Comment: Replace `<activity android:name=".MainActivity"` with `<activity android:name=".MainActivity">`

Comment: @YushinKim Looks like that class is not there in that package try with full package name where that class exists. Check the package name in Mainactivity.java(very first line) and use that

Comment: Thank you guys! I found problem. it was due to package name and directory. XD